# Visual Studio 2010 with phone tools - Any advanced/configurable settings?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, emulation

In Visual Studio 2008, there was the device manager for setting up additional templates and options for the emulator. None of these options are available with Visual Studio 2010 which I understand as the features were removed.

When the Phone Tools are installed, the device target box comes back but there are no options at all.

[image]

Basically, I was just wondering where this list gets its options from and if there is any way at all to configure it?

The closest I got to was find the `%LocalAppData%\microsoft\phone tools` folder, but not sure this is correct as it appears to be more related to the emulator itself (e.g. if deleted, it gets recreated when you run.).

([Link to something](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsoftdeviceemu/thread/5dda0416-a1ce-45fe-9997-d87691fe9f0d) a post that helped me years ago)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while, but it looks like I have found it.

I was on to the correct path with `%LocalAppData%\microsoft\phone tools`. All the targets are in the `conman_ds_platform.xslt` file.

I have no idea why they no longer provide an interface for customising - but it looks to me that despite MS taking the feature out of Visual Studio, it is still possible to customise this and add your own devices just fine.

[image]

... Next, depending on time, I will try to convert the Windows Mobile/CE project templates to VS 2010 and see if it is possible to do full development on Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: you may also want to look at some of the command line switches available to the emulator, to see a list run the following command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\1.0\xde.exe